# How to plot a grid of images and their categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a plot similar to this.

[image: this]

I have several pictures, each of which I have two lists for (both lists with 5 elements).

I want to plot the image with the two lists to its right. Since there are several pictures to do this for, it would be nice if it could be done in a tile/grid format.

My data looks like:

```
class0[i] = ['example0', 'example1', .., 'example4']
class1[i] = ['example0', 'example1', .., 'example4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using a grid of axes that can be pretty much any shape, and a table for pretty alignment of the class labels.

```
class0 = [['class0_{:d}'.format(i+1) for i in range(5)] for _ in range(10)]
class1 = [['class1_{:d}'.format(i+1) for i in range(5)] for _ in range(10)]

nrows, ncols = 5,2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols*2, figsize=(2*ncols*2,2*nrows))
for img_ax,txt_ax,curr_class0,curr_class1 in zip(axs.flat[0::2], axs.flat[1::2], class0, class1):
    img_ax.imshow(np.random.random(size=(5,5)))

    text = [[c,d] for c,d in zip(curr_class0,curr_class1)]
    txt_ax.table(cellText=text, loc='center', edges='open')
    txt_ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]